# What represents status 531 or 540 for uwsgi process in uwsgitop?

Tags: python-2.7, uwsgi, supervisord, uwsgi-stats-server

I'm running uwsgi with a 3 processes configuration. While monitoring it to see some problems with requests timeouts on a high traffic website (100 requests/second) I saw the following.

It seems that one of the processes is being locked into 531 (540 on another server) status and not serving any requests. Also EXC column stays between 11 and 15.

What is 531 status? I can't find any reference in uwsgitop documentation.
It should only be one of **idle, busy, pause, cheaped or sig**

I need to say that uwsgi runs under supervisor.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those numbers 531 and 540 do not really belong to the STATUS column, but to the SIG column. The real status was *idle*, which is the following value that's mistakenly being displayed under the AVG column.

It's just a display bug: seems a wide value under the REQ column has overflowed the column and pushed every subsequent value in that row 1 more position over to the right.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't realize that mismatch of columns. Thanks.